# How to wrap text in Photoshop like in terminal?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-wrap

I'm trying to get monospaced text in Photoshop to break mid-character. This is what the terminal does by default. Here's an example of what I want to happen:

[image: Example of word breaking mid-character.]

Here's what's happening in Photoshop:
[image: Example of word not breaking mid-character.]

How do I force a word to break mid-character in Photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* insert a **soft-return** by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and hitting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key where you want the break. But you'd have to do this manually. This is different than hyphenation, no hyphen should be inserted.

Photoshop is simply not geared towards using long strings of text the way something like a Terminal is. It's kind of a given than someone is *designing* a Photoshop document, not simply using it as a text editor.

Comment: Drat, that's exactly what I'm designing-- a text editor. But your answer works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the Hyphenation in the Paragraph Panel.

I do not know how to get rid of the Hyfen, but I think it will solve your problem breaking the word.

See the image below:

[image]